# Functional Programming: How does one create a new column to a dataframe that contains a multiindex column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, functional-programming

Suppose the below simplified dataframe.  (The actual df is much, much bigger.) How does one assign values to a new column `f` such that `f` is a function of another column (e.,g. `e`)? I'm pretty sure one needs to use `apply` or `map` but never done this with a dataframe that has multiindex columns?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("a", "d"), ("a", "e"), ("b", "d"), ("b","e")))
df
    a       b
    d   e   d   e
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
```

Desired output:

```
    a          b
    d   e   f  d   e   f
0   1   2   1  3   4   1
1   5   6   1  7   8  -1
2   9  10  -1  11  12 -1
3  13  14  -1  15  16 -1
```

Would like to be able to apply the following lines and assign them to a new column `f`.  Two problems: First, the last line that contains the `apply` doesn't work but hopefully my intent is clear. Second, I'm unsure how to assign values to a new column of a dataframe with a multi index column structure.  Would like to be able use functional programming methods.

```
lt = df.loc(axis=1)[:,'e'] < 8
gt = df.loc(axis=1)[:,'e'] >= 8
conditions = [lt, gt]
choices = [1, -1]
df.loc(axis=1)[:,'f'] = df.loc(axis=1)[:,'e'].apply(np.select(conditions, choices))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nms = [(i, 'f')for i, j in df.columns if j == 'e']    
df[nms] = (df.iloc[:, [j == 'e' for i, j in df.columns]] < 8) * 2 - 1

df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
df
 a          b       
    d   e  f   d   e  f
0   1   2  1   3   4  1
1   5   6  1   7   8 -1
2   9  10 -1  11  12 -1
3  13  14 -1  15  16 -1
```

EDIT:

for a custom ordering:

```
d = {i:j for j, i in enumerate(df.columns.levels[0])}
df1 = df.loc[:, sorted(df.columns, key = lambda x: d[x[0]])]
```

IF the whole data is in a way symmetric, you could do:

```
df.stack(0).assign(f = lambda x: 2*(x.e < 8) - 1).stack().unstack([1,2])
Out[]: 
    a          b       
    d   e  f   d   e  f
0   1   2  1   3   4  1
1   5   6  1   7   8 -1
2   9  10 -1  11  12 -1
3  13  14 -1  15  16 -1
```

Comment: thank you, however, column `f` should be adjacent to column `e`  as in the above.  The actual dataframe is many thousands of columns and will be very messy if not connected  as shown in the desired output above..

Comment: thank you but I can't assume that the column names will always be in alphabetical order.  Maybe there is another simple way to address the reordering but I was hoping for a more direct solution using functional programming methods such as `apply` or `map`.  Where `a` is treated as a sub dataframe and `b` as another data frame and so on...

Comment: @jgg what do you mean that some names are changed? your second `df` does not have `e` so there is no change.

Comment: you're right it works.  my fault.  But isn't there a way to do this with `map` and/or `apply` or some other functional programming technique?

Comment: these are just concatenated dataframes where each df contains the same columns.  The large data frame should be able to be split by the key and then a function applied and then the sub-dataframes combined.  i.e split-apply-combine.

Comment: @jgg. So do all the dataframes have the same structure? Do they have same columns with column names?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: @jgg try something like `df.stack(0).assign(f = lambda x: 2 * (x.e< 8) -1).unstack().stack(0).unstack()`

Comment: Was thinking along the lines of `groupby`.

Comment: @jgg you do not have to use a `groupby`. Check the last edit. i made

Comment: I know I do not have to use a groupby method but it is more concise and it adheres to the criteria I stated in the subject to use functional programming techniques.

Comment: @jgg I really cant help you now. `groupby` is to group rows not columns. You want to use something that cannot be used. Unless of course you stack all columns, reset the indices which is even harder than the last solution given. What's wrong with the stack solution I gave?

Comment: thank you.  nothing is wrong with your solution.  it's just a bit different than what I had in mind.  Was shooting for something using the guiding principle of split-apply-combine.